# Incorporate document features into shoebox app

Tags: macos, cocoa, printing, pagination, document-based

I'm working on a shoebox (library style) app for Mac OS X which will incorporate a page view like in Apple's text edit sample code.

Since this is a shoebox app, I cannot simply generate a document-based Xcode project because I want the user to generate a new "canvas" to work on from within the app. Rather than having the user open a new document through an open command they create a new object in the navigation sidebar, or simply open an already created document also from the sidebar. I'm looking at a UI similar to Albums in iPhoto.

Is there an easy way to incorporate the features of document-based applications (i.e. page setup, print setup etc) into a non-document-based app without having to implement each method individually? Would anyone have any suggestions as to how to implement this otherwise?